# How to make "Load More Articles" button? (similar to Facebook, twitter etc.)

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a site where users post their small articles. All articles display on my homepage. I would like to display 20 articles and then have "Load More" button at the bottom that ,when clicked, loads 10 more articles and again when clicked loads 10 more articles and so on.

Comment: Have you Googled for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit your initial results with a SQL limit (or something similar).
Then attach a click event to your button which triggers an ajax load of the next 10 articles.
(Not the most extensive answer, but then, neither is your question ;)).

(Tip: use jquery, it takes a lot of (event handling / ajax) out of your hands..)

Edit: Okay, try to combine the following:

http://api.jquery.com/click/
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_webforms_dynamic_load.ashx
http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2011/06/27/ajax-based-data-loading-using-jquery-load-function-in-asp-net.aspx

It's actually pretty basic what you try to do. Try to read some tutorials about jQuery with ASP:)!

Comment: im not good with jquery and javascript, plz if you have an example about that tell me .

Comment: thanx alot its perfect example